# MAMP losing one of my tables

Tags: database

I am using MAMP to host a Drupal-7 database on Mac OS 10.12 (Sierra).  It works just fine until the first time I sign out and shut down my computer.  When I come back, and try to "add content", I am informed that I have not yet defined any "content types". Yet when I go to "structure => content types" they are all there, as are all the pages I have already created. I can edit existing pages and do everything else. Status report looks clean. Is this a database problem? A MAMP problem? Something else?

Comment: Hi, I think it would be difficult to provide an answer because there are multiple questions here, and it would be difficult to identify what the issue could possibly be without access to the same information that you have locally.

Comment: At this point I'm pretty sure my databases are corrupted because drush gives me a database error when I try to archive.